# The set S is also bounded above by y/x, so it has a least upper bound α in the real numbers.

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

Given x = 2 and y = 5, let S be the set of all integers k such that 2k ≤ 5, i.e., S = {0, 1, 2}. Then the upper bound of S is y/x = 5/2, i.e., for any number greater than or equal to 5/2, it is greater than or equal to any element of S. Also, the least upper bound of S is 5/2, i.e., there is no smaller number that is also an upper bound of S. Therefore, α = 5/2.
**this is best example  of   The set S is also bounded above by y/x, so it has a least upper bound α in the real numbers.**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.